# Is it intentional to put default tags on search input?

Tags: bug

When I am on page https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered and have opened tab `my tags`, and then I click on `all questions`:

> [image]

then I don't see any questions cause of filled tags in search input.

> [image]

Is this behaviour intentional? Should my favourite tags be put in search input automatically?

Comment: What are the tags in the search and what are your ignored tags?

Comment: The one which appears in search input are my favourite tags, and ignored tags are the one mentioned here. I wonder if this tags should be prefilled there. I didn't put them there.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. The tags aren't copied automatically if you go from "my tags" to "newest" and then to "all questions"

Comment: It's good that we as a community is helping finding the real bugs out. It'd be fun watching these bug fixes taking 6-8 weeks or so.

Comment: @o_O 1 week so far ;)

Comment: @o_O you were saying? :D