# Semantics of closing as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently one of my [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357641/switching-from-unanswered-to-all-questions-leaves-incorrect-tag-filter-in-se) was closed as a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362806/is-it-intentional-to-put-default-tags-on-search-input).

While it can be argued whether they are exact duplicates, I am not here for that.

I want to point out that my question was posted **before** the other question. Infact it was posted more than 3 months before the new one.

Why this perturbs me is because I believe that questions being closed or marked duplicate has a negative effect on my account (I know this for the main site, not sure about meta).

So my questions are:

1. Does questions being marked as duplicate affect my accounts "score" ?
2. In case 2 questions are similar and both are of equal quality, should the newer question be always marked as a duplicate or there is no such rule?
3. If 2 is not true (and 1 is), what can I do in the future to avoid asking questions that are not an exact match of every question that will be ever be posted?

Comment: Since it's on Meta it matters little...but it does at least seem to me that the cardinality of this duplicate closure is backwards.

Comment: Have you seen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294000/a-question-marked-as-duplicate-but-is-older-than-the-linked-question and its duplicates?

Comment: @JonClements, wow! That was meta. If you could just clarify the first point of my question, I would remove this question.

Comment: I'm not sure they're even dupes... The community can always vote to reopen / close accordingly if they want to reverse the direction.

Comment: @JonClements:  That's why my hunch on the cardinality is that it's backwards.  The newer question *lacks* some details on the bug that the older question supplies.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no (publicly known) direct impact of duplicates to any of your "scores" (reputation, tag scores, ban counters...). It will indirectly impact your reputation as posts likely get significantly less attention and votes which helps for <strike>really bad</strike>not so well researched questions, but hurts ok ones.
2. Question with better answers should be used as duplicate target irrespective of question age, poster vote, phase of the Moon or any other factors. See [Old question marked as duplicate of a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315472/old-question-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-new-question)
3. Do your research and then ask questions if needed, explain why potential duplicates don't apply.